# Tiny TDS load error whilst running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tiny-tds

I get this error message when I run "rails server"

```
 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds (LoadError)
```

I have ruby-odbc 0.99994 and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.1 installed. My rails server version is 3.2.1.

can someone help me with this error message and how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Hi DJD, yeah I have done all that..but to no use. its just driving me nuts with this tiny_tds.

Comment: oh well I figured it out myself, cleaned out all the useless gems that were installed and did a gem cleanup -d and then a gem cleanup -v...it did it..all is good now